# Defining string arrays

Tags: c, arrays, string

Why is the following an acceptable way to initialize an array of strings:

```
char * strings[] = { "John", "Paul", NULL};
```

But this way will fail:

```
char ** strings = { "John", "Paul", NULL};
```

My thought was that it would work relatively the same as doing:

```
char string[] = "John";
char * string = "Paul";
```

Where both work. What's the difference between the two?

Comment: What error you got?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`char * strings[]` is an **array of pointers**. When you initialize it as

```
char * strings[] = { "John", "Paul", NULL};
```

the strings `John` `Paul` are **string literals**. They are constants that exist somewhere in the code or Read only memory. What is done is to copy the pointer to the string literal `John` into the `strings[0]` and so on. i.e.

```
strings[0] --> holds a pointer to "John". 
strings[1] --> holds a pointer to "Paul"
```

Note that the string literals should not be modified by your program. If you do, it is undefined behaviour.

---

In case of `char ** strings` This is a **pointer to a pointer**. It is a single memory location and cannot hold many pointers on its own.  So, you cannot initialize it as below.

```
char ** strings = { "John", "Paul", NULL};  // error
```

However, a pointer to pointer can be used along with dynamic memory allocation (`malloc`,`calloc` etc) to point to an array of strings.

---

```
char string[] = "John";
```

In this case, you have a **char array** into which the string literal is copied. This step is done by the compiler, generally in the start up code before the main starts.

---

```
char * string = "Paul";
```

Here you have a **char pointer**  which points to a string literal.

Difference between the above two statements is that in the case of a char array, you can modify the elements of `string` but you cannot in the second case.